# Closing a modal popup then show another one

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to close a modal and then open another one when an error occurs using AJAX. However it does not seem to work in the `error` function. It works fine in the `success` function.

```js
$('#modSending').modal({
  backdrop: 'static',
  keyboard: false
});

$.ajax({
  url: '/api/myapi/saverep?id=' + tid,
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'POST',
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  success: function(result) {
    //this part is working
    $('#modSending').modal('hide');
    $('#lblAlertHead').text("MySystem - Success");
    $('#pMessage').text("Request has been save.");
    $('#modAlert').modal({
      backdrop: 'static',
      keyboard: false
    });
    $('#btnAlertMsg').attr('onclick', "$('#modAlert').modal('hide')")
    $('#txtCategory').val('');
    cat_loadDetails(tg);
  },
  error: function(xhr) {
    var getxhr = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);

    //close modal modSending
    $('#modSending').modal('hide');
    $('#lblAlertHead').text("MySystem - Error");
    $('#pMessage').text(getxhr.Message);
    $('#btnAlertMsg').attr('onclick', "$('#modAlert').modal('hide')");

    //open modal modAlert
    $('#modAlert').modal({
      backdrop: 'static',
      keyboard: false
    });

    return;
  }
});
```

Comment: Which part specifically does/does not work? Any errors in the console?

Comment: The success part is working, the modSending is hiding then the modAlert is shown, but for the error part, modSending does not hiding but the modAlert is showing

Comment: The problem is maybe from the server side, you can alstro to add all arguments in the error: `error: function ( xhr, status, errorThrown ) { ` you could also try to use `.done()` and `.fail()` instead of success and error.

Comment: Hi everyone, my problem is the $('#modSending').modal('hide') does not work on error: function